# How could i get a one line output into a mutliple line one in powershell?

Tags: powershell

This is my command which i am using :

```
PS U:\> Get-ADUser paul -properties memberof | fl memberof
```

and my output looks like this:

```
memberof : {CN=WLAN-Allow,OU=Groups,OU=Users,OU=at,....}
```

So my question is how do i format my single line output into something which should like like a list:

```
memeberof :

 - CN=WLAN-Allow
 - OU=Groups
 - OU=Users
 - OU=at*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Gerald, the question is vague, you can list out each entry in member of using the code that Gerald has provided. If, for some reason (which I can't fathom) you need the output to show each directory object in the result set, this will do that:

```
Get-ADUser paul -properties memberof |  select -ExpandProperty memberof | %{
    $x = $_.Split(',');
    foreach($y in $x) {
        if($y -like 'CN=*') {
            $y
        } else {
            "`t$y"
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs like:

```
CN=Group One
        OU=Old AD Groups
        OU=Groups
        OU=GB
        DC=Company
        DC=net
CN=Group 2
        OU=Groups
        OU=Nested
        OU=GB
        DC=Company
        DC=net
```

Comment: No problem. What is this for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `select`:

```
Get-ADUser paul -Properties memberof | Select -ExpandProperty memberof
```

The result will be one line for every item in the list. I assume this is what you want, your example result doesn't make much sense.

```
CN=WLAN-Allow,OU=Groups,OU=Users,OU=at
CN=Group 2,OU=...
CN=Group 3,OU=...
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Your solution looks fine to me, but isn't there a possibility to format my previous single line output into a multiple line one ?

Comment: What do you want in each line? One line per DN or one line per element for every DN?

Comment: If you really want to get every DN element in a single line you only need to add `|% { $_.split(',') }` to my example. But I really don't know why one would want to do that.

Comment: Personally I'd have chosen your answer, I really have no idea why someone would want to spit this out.